# Entry not found in index

Tags: lotus-notes

I tried to get the specifc value of a field using dbLookup in a hidden view, but I get this error "field:Version:Entry not found in index". I am sure that the field Version was added as in the view as a column. Column 2 is the "Version field". How do I solve this one?

@DbLookup("":"NoCache";"":"";"(vwLDoc)";ParentId+@Text(Version); 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this code is in a field (?) Re-write your code like this

```
key := @trim(ParentID + @Trim(@Text(Version))); 
lkup := @DbLookup("":"NoCache";"":"";"(vwLDoc)";key; 2); 
val := @if(@IsError(lkup);@Text(lkup) + ", key:" + key;lkup);
val;
```

This allows you to separate the key from the DBLookup, so that you can investigate what actual value is being used to run the lookup. Concatenating 2 strings together can result in extra spaces being inserted thus creating an invalid key value.

It also handles errors more elegantly, as you can use the "val" variable without causing an ugly prompt box to appear, which also affects forms when opening them.

I would check that the view "(vwLDoc)" has a sorted column. If there are no sorted columns in the view the dblookup will always return "entry not found in index".

You can test for the key by opening the view and the just typing the key value and it should jump to any matching documents. To open hidden views simply select "View"=> "Goto" (hold the ctrl-shift key down when you do this to see hidden views), and then select the view.

If you paste the entire formula where you're using this dblookup, I can provide a better answer.

Comment: Giulio- Thank you. I sort the field Version and it works. Not I get the value.

Comment: Anyway do you have an idea on how to get the latest document created by category in View using lotus notes @formula?

Comment: You can add a new column and put in the formula @Created. Make that column sortable as either ascending/descending. Note that the way a view sorts documents is dependent on the left-to-right order of "sorted" columns. So, if this new column is added to the right of an existing sorted column the first columns' sorting will take precedence, then the next sorted column and so on. So you may have to move them around to get the desired result. (I don't recommend doing too many sorted columns, 3 or 4 should be enough.)

Comment: Ok. But forgot to tell you, the document is duplicate(for eg. project name, type, number) most of the time. So I want to get the latest one only with unique project name,type and number. Is this possible with the solution above?

Comment: You're getting 2 questions answered here, for the price of one..LOL. Duplicate values on separate documents that appear in a view will be sorted in date order if you add the @Created column as described above as the view column is concerned with sorting on @Created date. Just remember that the left-to-right order of sorted columns impacts how the view sort the documents.

Comment: @giulio-I tried the solution above the result is it will display duplicate documents. I put the @Created on the first column. The @created is the only sorted field, the others are not sorted.

Comment: even I move the @created from 1st, or2nd , or 3rd. the result is still the same, it displays duplicate documents

Comment: So out of a group of documents that have duplicated values on them, you just want only one of documents to be in the view ? Not sure if I understand the requirements for this :/

Comment: Yes! Actually I created another turnaround to solve this problem. I made an agent which run when I click the button.Then search the document having the same name with the one that I currently saving then update the value to of the latest field to 0 and save the latest one to 1.